# Azure WebRole can not start up normally in emulator

Tags: azure, android-emulator, azure-web-roles

I try to run a azure project under emulator with Ctrl + F5 under visual studio and encountered some problems. My web role can not start up normally. The azure sdk version is 2.2 and visual studio 2012 is used.

When checked the WaIISHost.log, I found the below exception:

```
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:14.949, INFO ] Starting host process.
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:16.477, INFO ] DebuggerAttachStart START
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:16.519, INFO ] Found role model xml file
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:16.727, INFO ] Creating endpoint IPAddress:127.255.0.0 PortNum:444  Protocol:https HostHeader:
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:16.728, INFO ] Adding site to AppModel with name , endpoints https:127.255.0.0:444:
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:16.999, INFO ] Reacl all resources for iis users
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.021, INFO ] Reacl all resources for iis users has been finished.
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.081, INFO ] Wait for iisconfigurator initialization global event to be set
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.082, INFO ] Found iisconfigurator initialization global event
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.082, INFO ] Iisconfigurator initialization global event set
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.251, INFO ] Changing operation timeout to 00:05:00
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:17.3, INFO ] Attempt Deploy with RoleInstanceId=deployment22(479).XXX RoleRoot=XXX optional SitesDestination=
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:18.035, INFO ] Successfully deployed sites
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:18.038, INFO ] StartDebuggingInformationEndpoint START
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:18.073, INFO ] StartDebuggingInformationEndpoint END
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000001, 2014/08/21 09:57:18.076, INFO ] DebuggerAttachComplete START
WaIISHost Information: 0 : [00018004:00000008, 2014/08/21 09:57:21.138, ERROR] Unhandled exception: IsTerminating 'True', Message 'System.InvalidOperationException: the role environment has not been initialized
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 1 : Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: the role environment has not been initialized
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I search the internet a lot and can not come up with a solution for this. Has anyone know something about that? Any advice is appreciated.

Continue:
I am able to start up the web role normally afterI reboot my machine. But the root cause for the problem is still unclear to me. Keep the questions here in case someone might have the same problem with me.

Comment: have you started VS in administror mode?

Comment: @techmike2kx, my VS is started in administrator mode.